# Diodes in series

Tags: diodes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsHweZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diodes are both made of Silicon. What will be the voltage across D1?.

Edit:

I voted for 0V only.

But this is the solution given.
[image]

Comment: Are they ideal diodes? If so, does it matter that they are made of silicon? If they're real, what kind of model would you use? It might get more complicated.

Comment: I would vote for 0V, since if they are made of silicon I'd expect D2 to want to drop ~700mV, which would leave nothing at all at the junction of the two diodes.

Comment: Even i thought 0V only. I have added the solution given, but it didn't made any sense.

Comment: there is nothing because silicon might not even turn on until 700mV, let alone the fact there are two blocking all current flow in the loop.

Comment: *Hint:* There are **TWO** things to consider in this circuit. One is the reverse (leakage) current of D1 and the other is the forward voltage drop produced by this current in D2 as the leakage current will flow through both devices, so the answer is not 0V.

Comment: Well, I just simulated it and got 500mV. However, the moment you add a load to that node so some current flows the voltage plummets.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle Spice simulation gives 36.3mV for the forward-biased diode using a "Telefunken" 1N4148 model with Isr = 1.565nA/Is = 2.682nA and nr = 2. Pretty close to the closed-form calculated result.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The simulator I use (Falstad) is very much a "rough guess" simulator. It doesn't really do a good job of precise calculations, and doesn't use real components. However, it is incredibly fast and simple to use, and can give ball-park figures to give you an idea of what you should be looking for.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle Fair enough. 0.5V is a good enough guess for most practical purposes anyhow. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Shockley diode equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Shockley_diode_equation).

\$I = I_S(e^{V_D\over nV_T}-1)\$

\$I_S\$ is reverse saturation current

\$V_D\$ is the diode voltage (positive for forward bias)

\$V_T\$ is the thermal voltage (~26mV at room temperature)

\$n\$ is the ideality factor (between 1 and 2)

You know one diode has a positive forward voltage and the other has a negative voltage across it. You know the currents are equal and you know the voltages must add up to the input voltage. So, you have two equations in two unknowns- solve.

I get 18mV and 481mV for diodes with an ideality factor of 1 (eg. diode-connected transistors).

Edit: I see your textbook solution now- it's a bit different because the ideality factor of two was assumed. They simply substituted (2nd line) and solved to get the result.

To visualize what's going on- the current through the reverse-biased diode will be approximately \$I_S\$ no matter the voltage (assuming it's not too close to zero). That's because (with a negative sign indicating reverse bias) the exponential term quickly gets << 1 as reverse bias increases, so the 1 dominates- also why it is called saturation current.

\$I_S\$ is something like \$10^{-9}\$ ~ \$10^{-14}\$ A for a real diode, so the diode that is forward biased will need to have very little voltage across it to conduct such a small forward current. While you'd probably lose marks for assuming I \$\approx\$ \$I_S\$, I think the insight may be valuable.

---

Edit: To clarify here- there are a number of possible diode models. For pedagogic purposes, the text has encouraged the use of the Shockley model because it gives a useful answer and is not too complex to be solved by a student to yield a closed-form solution. I'll review the models we've discussed here and the results below:

1. Diode that is 'on' when Vf > 0 and 'off' when Vf <=0: indeterminate unless you assume leakage or load.
2. Diode that is 'on' when Vf > 0.7V and 'off' when Vf <= 0.7V: indeterminate unless you assume leakage or load.
3. Shockley equation with n = 2: V1 = 0.036V V2 = 0.464V
4. SPICE simulation with 1N4148 model Telefunken: V1 = 0.0363V V2 = 0.4637V (solved numerically, not closed-form)

Comment: Great minds think alike - fools seldom differ (+1)

Comment: Thank you for that. But what i thought was, current through D2 should be given Shockley Diode equation, and through D1 will be Is, and both should be equal right? . But how the voltage across D1 would come into the equation in the solution? 
Edit: Voltage across D2 wouldn't be affected that much since it is exp(-ve). And V1=V-V2 right?
Perfect!

Comment: Nice, most real diodes I've looked at have an ideality factor near 2.  (Those were pn diodes, I don't know about schottkies.)

Comment: Just one simple doubt, is the knee voltage included in the diode current equation?. If the knee voltage was not zero,and is 0.7V, will the current flow through D2?

Comment: @AnjanaVerma Yes, the Shockley equation describes the DC behavior of the (ideal) diode fully with any bias voltage.  (Note that reverse breakdown is not included in the model, nor is the series resistive term that SPICE models incorporate- the former is only important at large reverse voltage and the latter at large forward current). In fact, apparently SPICE assumes |I| = Is for V < -5*n*Vt, the same approximation I referred to above. See [here](http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/7292572.PDF).

Comment: That was very useful. So we have solved the problem assuming diodes are ideal, if the diode has a built in potential of 0.7 V, then the applied voltage should be more than that to turn the diode D2 on right?

Since applied voltage is 0.5V, D2 would be OFF hence the Shockley equation cannot be applied, right?

For a non ideal diode(Vbi=0.7V ) . If we apply say 5V across it, what should we use as Vd in Shockley's equation, 5V or 5-0.7 V?

Comment: @AnjanaVerma Shockley's equation is a different model from the one using 0.7V. Think of four different models in order of increasing accuracy. 1. Diode is on for Vf > 0, off for Vf <=0. 2. Diode is on for Vf > 0.7V, off for Vf < 0.7V. 3. Shockley equation. 4. SPICE standard model. Of course more complex and accurate models are possible, but don't mix them- use the appropriate one for the task.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with Spehro Pefhany. Just append the equations.

Assume the two diodes are the same. And assume the voltage direction and current  direction both are from the D2's anode to D2's cathode.

[image]